# Предупреждения о несоответствии типов при использовании _Generic

Tags: c, generics, c11

Разбираясь с `_Generic` из C11, написал простой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define swap(a, b) _Generic((a), \
    int*: swap_int(a, b), \
    float*: swap_float(a, b) \
)

void swap_int(int* a, int* b) {
    int tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp;
}

void swap_float(float* a, float* b) {
    float tmp = *a; *a = *b; *b = tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int a = 10, b = 40;
    float c = 3.14, d = 2.71;

    printf("a = %d    b = %d\n", a, b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a = %d    b = %d\n\n", a, b);

    printf("c = %.2f  d = %.2f\n", c, d);
    swap(&c, &d);
    printf("c = %.2f  d = %.2f\n", c, d);
}
```

Программа работает верно, но при компиляции появляются предупреждения о несоответствии типов:

```
temp.c: In function 'main':
temp.c:819:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap_float' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&a, &b);
          ^
temp.c:799:24: note: in definition of macro 'swap'
     float*: swap_float(a, b) \
                        ^
temp.c:808:6: note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int *'
 void swap_float(float* a, float* b) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
temp.c:819:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'swap_float' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&a, &b);
              ^
temp.c:799:27: note: in definition of macro 'swap'
     float*: swap_float(a, b) \
                           ^
temp.c:808:6: note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int *'
 void swap_float(float* a, float* b) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
temp.c:823:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap_int' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&c, &d);
          ^
temp.c:798:20: note: in definition of macro 'swap'
     int*: swap_int(a, b), \
                    ^
temp.c:802:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'float *'
 void swap_int(int* a, int* b) {
      ^~~~~~~~
temp.c:823:14: warning: passing argument 2 of 'swap_int' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     swap(&c, &d);
              ^
temp.c:798:23: note: in definition of macro 'swap'
     int*: swap_int(a, b), \
                       ^
temp.c:802:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'float *'
 void swap_int(int* a, int* b) {
```

Как их убрать?

Компилятор: `gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)`

Comment: Откровенно говоря, _Generic я тоже толком не освоил.  Для случаев, подобных вашему использую макросы вот такого вида `#define SWAP(x, y) ({__typeof__(x) _t = x; x = y; y = _t;})` прямо для имен  и для  указателей -- 
`#define PSWAP(x, y) ({__typeof__(*x) _t = *(x); *(x) = *(y); *(y) = _t;})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае можно просто немного поменять синтаксис макроса:

```
#define swap(a, b) _Generic((a), \
    int*: swap_int, \
    double*: swap_double, \
    float*: swap_float \
)((a),(b))
```

Возможно есть и более удачные решения. Я `_Generic` пока глубоко не копал...

**Update:** *Всё что дальше — строго моё мнение и размышления.*

Это фактически переписанный пример из стандарта. Ответить болей-менее я могу на вопрос «как он работает»: `_Generic` выражение фактически «имеет значение» указателя на соответствующую функцию, который затем вызывается с аргументами `а` и `b`. Но у этого способа есть ограничения: это не сработает например, если `swap_int` будет макросом или если у одной из функций будут другие элементы.

Принимая это во внимание, изначальный вариант более гибкий. Умозрительно я также могу объяснить почему в реализации gcc при обработке оного присутствуют предупреждения: фактически выражения присутствуют в тексте и проверка на корректность указателей происходит до раскрытия `_Generic`. Однако я не вижу в коде ничего криминального и ИМХО они ложно-положительные, так что стоит обсудить этот пример в месте где обитают более сведущие люди, например, в мейллисте gcc или в багзилле.

Кроме того чтобы подавить предупреждения можно воспользоваться хаком: явно привести указатели к нужному типу или `(void*)`.

```
#define swap(a, b) _Generic((a), \
    int*:    swap_int    ((void*)a, (void*)b), \
    double*: swap_double ((void*)a, (void*)b), \
    float*:  swap_float  ((void*)a, (void*)b)  \
)
```